# Location of odbc library on ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, odbc, unixodbc, ubuntu-13.10

I can't find the location of library for odbc on Ubuntu 13.10.
I have installed unixodbc with this command :

```
sudo apt-get install unixODBC unixODBC-dev
```

But under /usr/local i can't find nothing.
Someone know the correct location of library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant say for certain, on my (different version of Ubuntu, 12.04.3 LTS ) its in:

/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.1

But you should find it with:

find / -name "libodbc.so*"

Comment: Yes the location is correct, but before I need to install libmyodbc.